# GLOBIGNORE does not work with sudo command

Tags: bash, sudo, tail

I'm using a mini shell script in order to 'tail' (in real time) a bunch of log files.

```
#!/bin/sh

oldGLOBIGNORE=$GLOBIGNORE

export GLOBIGNORE='foo-bar.log'

sudo -E tail -f -n0 /var/log/*.log

GLOBIGNORE=$oldGLOBIGNORE
```

As you can see, I want to log all files except the one named `foo-bar.log`.

the `-E` option of sudo should allow me to keep the `GLOBIGNORE` variable but it looks like it does not work.

I'm testing on Ubuntu 10.04, bash 4.1.5.

Any clue ?

Comment: Is `/bin/sh` Bash on your system? It isn't always...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly — `GLOBIGNORE` relates to the full filepath resulting from filename-expansion, not just the last part. So you actually want to write `GLOBIGNORE='/var/log/foo-bar.log'`.

Secondly — you don't actually need to export `GLOBIGNORE` into the environment and add `-E`, because the `/var/log/*.log` gets expanded by Bash before it even invokes `sudo`.

Thirdly — your approach to saving the old value of `GLOBIGNORE` and restoring it afterward is less than ideal, because the behavior when `GLOBIGNORE` is unset is different from its behavior when it's set-but-empty, and your script can never restore it to being unset. Fortunately, the script doesn't *need* to restore it (since it's not as though a script's variables could continue to have effect after the script returns), so you can just remove that stuff.

All told, you can write:

```
#!/bin/sh

GLOBIGNORE=/var/log/foo-bar.log
sudo tail -f -n0 /var/log/*.log
```

Comment: I am starting the script directly via its name (because it is in `/usr/bin`). I've tried you second code, and even if I put GLOBIGNORE=*.log, I still have all files listed

Comment: @magnetik: Re: first sentence: O.K., I've edited my answer to trim out the stuff that's irrelevant for that. Re: second sentence: Assuming your `/bin/sh` is Bash, this *should* work. Have you checked to make sure that `/bin/sh` is Bash on your system?

Comment: Humm yep it was Dash ! Thanks for you answer, the explainations and the folow up !